# SQL Server date setting

Tags: sql, sql-server

running to a small issue.
I have a scrpit that based on date. what i need is to retrieve data that is 14 days ago not including the date it was run. 
example; date run 12/15/2016  should retrieve Data between 12/1/2016 - 12/14/2016.
The issue i have is it ends with the date was run. see below the criteria I set.

```
where a.UF_1 <> '' and (DATEDIFF(dd, a.TRANSACTION_DATE, getdate()) <14)
```

any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: ```getdate()``` returns current timestamp so any records with TRANSACTION_DATE between midnight last night and just now will be included in your results. So instead of getdate(), if you use ```convert(varchar,getdate(),101)```, that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this:

`where a.UF_1 <> '' and cast(a.TRANSACTION_DATE as date) between cast(getdate()-14 as date) and cast(getdate()-1 as date)`.

I assume that neither `a.UF_1` or `a.TRANSACTION_DATE` is nullable.. otherwise handle this.

Answer (score 4):

```
select *  from yourTable 
where datecolumn < getdate() 
  and datecolumn >=dateadd(dd,-14,getdate())
```

OR . . . .

```
declare @someDateVariable datetime - '12/15/2016'
select *  
from yourTable 
where cast(datecolumn as date) < cast(@someDateVariable as date) 
  and datecolumn >= dateadd(dd,-14,@someDateVariable)
```

Comment: Edited the question and posted two answers in 120 seconds after the question was posted. I want some of whatever you're on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it 's still pulling up the run date.

Comment: @Messi because you need to case GETDATE() as DATE since it is a DATETIME format.

Comment: I have done that but no luck. I used Richard and it returned the result i need.

Comment: That's fine @Messi  but you want to avoid using subtraction on dates without the DATEADD function